# Zend framework Json engine?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework

Is there some kind a engine for Json in the Zend framework, What I mean is some abstraction that all the Json (ajax) responces go through ?
in other words some class to controll all the Ajax calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zend_Json_Server - JSON-RPC server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.server.html) might do what you are looking for:

> Zend_Json_Server is a » JSON-RPC server implementation. It supports both the » JSON-RPC version 1 specification as well as the » version 2 specification; additionally, it provides a PHP implementation of the » Service Mapping Description (SMD) specification  for providing service metadata to service consumers.

Apart from that, there is also [Zend_JSON](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.introduction.html), that

> provides convenience methods for serializing native PHP to JSON and decoding JSON  to native PHP. […] In addition, Zend_Json provides a useful way to convert any arbitrary XML formatted string into a JSON formatted string. This built-in feature will enable PHP developers to transform the enterprise data encoded in XML  format into JSON format before sending it to browser-based Ajax client applications.

Also see these articles by

- [Matthew Weier O'Phinney on Responding to Different Content Types in RESTful ZF Apps](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/233-Responding-to-Different-Content-Types-in-RESTful-ZF-Apps.html) and
- [Ciaran McNulty on Clarifying Javascript-PHP communication using JSON-RPC](http://ciaranmcnulty.com/blog/2010/03/clarifying-javascript-php-communication-using-json-rpc)

Comment: +1, Zend_Json_Server is what you want.  I wrote a blog post about it yesterday, coincidentally: http://ciaranmcnulty.com/blog/2010/03/clarifying-javascript-php-communication-using-json-rpc

Comment: @Ciaran Nice. I was trying to find a decent article on Json_Server, so I added yours to the answer.

Comment: Thanks seniors -- as always valuable responses

Comment: btw I am really confused (and my Flexibility part is bugging me)

ok lets say I have a form User Registration. I use it from JS. with a load(just get the html code) and it uses XMLhttp request right, then I need this for for Ajax again Xmlhttp request, but here I have to echo out JsonEncoded info and turn off View renderer, (problems starting) and after while I will need it with just regular request. so the dilemma is to handle it in a flexible way or have bunch of actions for different requests, but this way it is same hard coded . anyhow I am just confused - will appreciate ur advice

Comment: @simple please go through the two linked articles. If there is any questions then, open another question. The Comment Sections is akward for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague and could be interpreted in two ways.

a.  You are just trying to serve ajax actions through your controllers.

This is pretty simple to achieve using the [context switch action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

b.  You want to serve JSON responses via an API, whether it be to use internally or externally.

If that is the case, [Zend_Rest_Controller](http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework) is probably the direction you want to go in.

I hope this helps.